# Spring Integration Java DSL - What is the difference between class HeaderEnricher and HeaderEnricherSpec

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am learning pre-Java8 DSL for spring integration, and trying out some examples from existing integration components available in my project. For header enricher, I came across two classes, HeaderEnricher, and HeaderEnricherSpec.

What is the difference in these classes, I observed that HeaderEnricherSpec extends the HeaderEnricher class. How does IntegrationComponentSpec help in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HeaderEnricherSpec` is a *builder* pattern implementation for the `HeaderEnricher`.

The general code looks like:

```
public class HeaderEnricherSpec extends IntegrationComponentSpec<HeaderEnricherSpec, HeaderEnricher> {
   ...
   @Override
    protected HeaderEnricher doGet() {
        HeaderEnricher headerEnricher =
                new HeaderEnricher(new HashMap<String, HeaderValueMessageProcessor<?>>(this.headerToAdd));
        headerEnricher.setDefaultOverwrite(this.defaultOverwrite);
        headerEnricher.setShouldSkipNulls(this.shouldSkipNulls);
        headerEnricher.setMessageProcessor(this.messageProcessor);
        return headerEnricher;
    }
}
```

The `IntegrationComponentSpec` is a "super" builder with common properties for any Specs for the Integration components.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification